# Can't load JS file served by PHP from an Android WebView

Tags: javascript, php, android, webview, content-type

I run a tool that is mostly used via a browser, but with a few flows managed with and Android App that also use webviews (with Android 4.4.2 for the oldest).
I use a PHP system to load certain JS files that are outside my web root.

From a browser (Desktop or Android Chrome), no problem, the file is served and interpreted as JS
From my app WebView, the JS file don't seems interpreted as Javascript, and I can see in the webview debugging this error message :

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >`

The script that serve JS is really simple :

```
<?
ob_start();
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo file_get_contents("/folder/file.js");
exit;
?>
```

I've try to change content-type with text/javascript or application/octet-stream but it don't change the problem.

Any idea how to force the webview to consider this file as a JS?

Here is the URL that load this JS ! https://example.com/loader.php?js=myfilen, do you think it can be related to the filename that include PHP and not JS?

Thanks a lot for your feedbacks & ideas ;)

Comment: Worth trying `application/javascript` instead of `text/plain`. Besides, isn't this javascript meant to be run on some html page? I would think so it is in webview.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your feedback !
I still have same issue with this Content-Type  :(

Comment: I finally understand that my problem is related to the JS file, that is ES6 Javascript and my webview don't seems to understand such JS...  

I now need to find how to convert this file to old school ES5 Javascript...

Comment: Then you may want to search for keywords like `transpiling` and `babel` :)